# How can I retrieve more than 10 trending topics for Twitter via the REST API?

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to retrieve **more than 10** trending topics for Twitter. For example, in 1.0 API, it was possible to get 20 topics using the daily endpoint.

Is there any way at all to achieve this using API 1.1? Or are we definitely only limited to 10?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/trends/place) is very clear on this.

> Returns the top 10 trending topics for a specific WOEID, if trending information is available for it.

The best you can do is to cache the response, then request it every 5 minutes and add trends to your list.

You could also request for several nearby locations - to see if that gives you sufficient trending topics.